# Highlight columns in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables for displaying paginated results.

In one use case of my requirement I need to highlight certain columns in a row. These columns would vary from Row to Row. Also information regarding the columns to be highlighted for each row is obtained at runtime i.e after the ajax call for the result set is made.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: How do you know which columns to highlight for a row?

Comment: it is determined per row basis during the ajax call for result data. Currently it comes as a hidden column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a `click` listener to each row that looks up the cells to highlight for that row using jQuery and then adds the highlighting style to that cell. Since a table can have many rows, it's best to use a delegated event handler (one handler for all rows in a table).

In this example, I used the `data()` method to store and retrieve an array of up to 3 random columns to highlight, though you could adapt the click handler to look up the value from a hidden column.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4pBVV/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            var colsToHighlight = [];
            for(var i=0; i<2; i++) {
                colsToHighlight.push(parseInt((Math.random() * 10), 10) % 5); // pick up to 3 random columns to highligh, may be less due to collisions
            }
            $(nRow).data('highlightCols', colsToHighlight);
        }
    });
} );

$('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    var row = $(this);
    var colsToHighlight = row.data('highlightCols');
    for(var i=0; i<colsToHighlight.length; i++) {
        row.find('td:eq(' + colsToHighlight[i] + ')').addClass('highlight'); //look up column by index and add highlight class
    }    
});
```

Comment: I have not followed the exact same approach as yours but I got the idea. thanks